# Eclipse Hellios 3.6

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Google plugin on Eclipse 3.6, but I can't create web applications because of an error (and a large error log file is created). What is reason for these errors?

Here was a full list, but I have deleted it because of the maximum 30000 characters. I have left this part:

```
!SESSION 2010-06-23 09:50:36.994 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2010-06-23 09:50:50.417
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
!SESSION 2010-06-24 12:08:50.787 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2010-06-24 12:09:02.298
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2010-06-30 18:23:18.566
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception during blocked modal context.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3884)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3885)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3506)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.disconnectFromWorkspace(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postShutdown(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:316)
```

Here is another list:

```
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendSelectionEvent(Widget.java:1093)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link.wmNotifyChild(Link.java:1071)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5096)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1887)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:4726)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4215)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2362)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link.callWindowProc(Link.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmLButtonUp(Widget.java:2056)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_LBUTTONUP(Control.java:4516)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link.WM_LBUTTONUP(Link.java:909)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4196)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2459)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
        at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.actions.AbstractOpenWizardAction.run(AbstractOpenWizardAction.java:103)
        at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.actions.OpenNewWebApplicationWizardToolbarAction.run(OpenNewWebApplicationWizardToolbarAction.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved deleting *.snap from the workspace dir:

> metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting eclipse with "clean " option . From the command-line  execute "eclipse.exe -clean".